# Any method to check balance of particular address in bitcoin core (0.18) using json rpc?

Tags: bitcoin-core

Setup bitcoin core (0.18) in my local node.In new version maximum methods are deprecated.I create new address using json rpc method and send some coin s on it.Now I am unable to check the balance of particular address.In this link its shows I received some amount. https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/37pwsrhT3gkWpDgTxskWf4m4eUiZ9CXJzJ

I am getting issue in many method.I try to use sendtoaddress method using jsonrpc but how they will recognize from which account I will transfer amount.

I also try to dumpprivate key of some address but this method returns me blank array.

Please help me out from all of this issues.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: your node bitcoin core is synchronized with the network?

Comment: Bitcoin Core has never supported computing the balance of an individual address.

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo  synchronization is in process  95% completed.

Comment: @PieterWuille If Bitcoin core is not suppoted invidiual address balance how can I  check that aacount have btc and how I will do transaction from that account .can you please help me.

Comment: @PieterWuille Is sendtoaddress automatically pickup the address from which amount address I want to send amount.There is anny other method which differ the from and to address.

Comment: @Nandhi That's not how Bitcoin works; internally there are no addresses or accounts.

Comment: Sorry, the intrusion @PieterWuille, I have a question on this problem, the bitcoin core not have the easy possibility to check the balance of the particular address but is possible do it, right? an example with the rpc command listtransactions? or I don't understand this problem? its just my curiosity

Comment: 1) Addresses don't have a balance (at the protocol level). It's possible to define address balance as the sum of the value of all UTXOs for a given address, but this isn't actually useful for anything but debugging, because (a) you shouldn't reuse addresses and (b) just having an address and its balance is not enough to spend coins (you need to know the actual UTXOs in order to spend them). (2) No, Bitcoin Core has no way of computing this for arbitrary addresses, at all.

Comment: It is possible to import a particular address as watch-only using importaddress/importmulti, and then rescan the chain for existing transactions affecting that address. Then you can use listunspent and sum up all UTXOs for that address. That works, but it's incredibly slow (may take hours, and needs the full chain locally). It's also pointless; a wallet is not just a single address, and generally you care about all UTXOs combined, not just those currently assigned to a single address

Comment: So @PieterWuille, is possible to get the amount on the specific address if I parsing the RPC response. It is not useful and bitcoin core works against this idea, but if I want to put my address for github donations, I can see the amount my donation balance is total sum value "listuspend" for addresses, right?

Comment: Also if I have the my address on the green wallet, is possible to import the specific address inside the bitcoin core but he is forced to scan all the blocks and reconstruct the history of the address, right?

Comment: You can use `listreceivedbyaddress` instead to see how much you've received on an address. How much is left on that address should be irrelevant to you. As soon as you make a transaction with the Green wallet, some of the funds will move elsewhere, and that's ok.

Comment: My point is that almost always, even in this case, you care about either how much you've received, or about how much is left _in your entire wallet_. Trying to deduct this information from individual address balances is an unnecessary complication that will just leave you confused.

Comment: Yes is unnecessary complication, thank so much :)

Comment: @Pieter Wuille Actually I am creating jsonrpc method API's for my exchange.If one user want to buy btc and other want to sell btc then which rpc  method  I will use to do transaction.How I will deduct btc from one user address and send to another user address?Which method work for this process.

Comment: @Nandni Use a proper database outside of Bitcoin Core to keep track of how much every user has.

Comment: @PieterWuille thanks for your support. Yes I am tracking record of each user how much every user have BTC .I have query. If one user wants to buy some btc from other user then which RPC method  I will call to send amount like when I am using "sendtoaddress" method then I will  mention  where from which account to send amount .Is there any method which is clear to me that from this account I am sending amount to this user.